# I've installed BeautifulSoup4 in jupyter notebook. Error comes up when trying to use "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd
```

**raise ImportError** 'You are trying to use a Python 3-specific version of Beautiful Soup under Python 2. This will not work. The final version of Beautiful Soup to support Python 2 was 4.9.3.'

**ValueError:** source code string cannot contain null bytes

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are not using the good version of Python.
Which version are you using in your NoteBook ?
You can find it in the top right corner 
[Version Python On VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUpHG.png)

You can change it easily just by clicking on it
If it's not working, You should install BeautifulSoup with the right version of Python : 
-> pip install beautifulsoup4
or maybe more :
-> pip3 install beautifulsoup4

after that relauch VSCode

I hope that I helped you :)

Comment: Already install these cmd  >> pip install beautifulsoup4  ,  pip3 install beautifulsoup4                     Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\qasim\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.11.1)Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\qasim\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.3.1)

Comment: What is the Python version you use in the Jupyter NoteBook?